# Dealing with part time manager whose approval is required daily

Tags: manager

Due to some org changes my team now has a manager who only works three days a week. I'm finding this very frustrating given how often I require her to click a button to approve things.

Given the main responsibility she has is to supervise and approve the things we are doing, I can't imagine her delegating this approval authority as it would make her redundant but the team is essentially blocked two days a week.

Of course she can just work through the backlog when she returns, but this is causing a bottle neck in a time sensitive process.

What can I suggest to overcome this?

Comment: Have you brought this up with you manager at all? What did they say about it? Are they happy for the delays?

Comment: I'm assuming this change is already in place. What sort of impact is there from time sensitive things not being approved until a day later (or whatever the delay is)? I think the place to start with bringing this up has to be "what's the business impact" (which is more than just finding it frustrating). Presumably she has a boss who approved the part time working, who knows that she's the one who has to click the button on these things.

Comment: Can you explain more about what kinds of things need button-click approval?

Comment: Do you actually need her to approve task A before you start task B?

Answer (score 16):

> What can I suggest to overcome this?

Call your manager.

Ask her what you should do to get approval on the days she is not working.

Listen to how she expects the process to work now. Then follow her instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Get used to the fact that approval processes take longer. I know what you mean and I can empathize with it: Sometimes, one thing is there for approval. With us, it wasn't about days, more about weeks, but it's also nerve-wracking when it remains waiting for long on the acceptance side (and they don't have to obey you) and opposed to it, you have responsibility to the payer that things go on with progress.

It only helps to get used to it, and also to tell the payer, yes, I have finished and my work is here for approval, but that is still pending. I also said, because this is not a taboo with us: You may contact the approval person, so that they please process this promptly.

This is a situation you can't escape from. Make yourself aware that there is nothing you can do about it, and think about how you can design your workflow so that it causes little or no problems.

For me, I found two solutions:

- Working on different threads. Even if that is uncomfortable: Carry on a little with each thread, and the thread then waits for approval, and then you continue. That is more of a breadening to do it that way.
- Work on the same thread and put the first piece in approval and do the next as a successor to approval, and also indicate that. For the first thing, the authority must in some way approve your first job, otherwise further work will be lost.

This is a game that one has to get used to. But I know your feelings and I want to say that it feels uncomfortable, I know that very well. I hope you can find a way how best to do that.

Comment: What is "breadening"?

Answer (score -2):

Isn`t planning a big part of development process?

I can't imagine situation where approval process cannot be scheduled and require daily ad-hoc interference by management.

My suggestion would be to build process in accordance to manager`s schedule.

Move meetings to morning of his / her work days and schedule the work in between them

Comment: Looks like you're assuming the OP works in some form of development. In reality, it could be any type of work.

Comment: such a good point @GregoryCurrie .  Annoyingly there are SOO many software industry questions on here, it's a common assumption/mistake :/

Comment: @GregoryCurrie How does development differ from any type of business? :)  Also, OP didnt specified industry.

Comment: @Strader Your answer referred to "sprints".  While in general agile methodologies can be applied to any business, they are typically only viewed as being in the domain of software development.

Comment: @PeterM Sounds good. I will update my answer

Comment: Regarding development, not every job is about creating something. For instance, the manager may need to authorise every large sale. How do you plan ahead for a customer entering the store and purchasing something?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie this hypothetical doesn't make sense.  Daily sales approval would not be  required from part time employee

Comment: @Strader I can easily imagine scenarios where large sales where there is negotiating involved may need to be authorised by a supervisor. A part time supervisor is certainly not ideal, but may absolutely be an oversight. Which is why my comment involves asking the supervisor. In any case, your answer still assumes development.

Answer (score -2):

You can not - you are not in a position to suggest anything. You can mention it higher up, but basically: org does stupid things, org lives with the consequences. I would play the game by just saying nothing, submit things right when she leaves when doable and let the fallout fall where it belongs. A little "Submitted at X, not processed by approver until Y" is easily proven and just what I would write in my email. Let the Supervisor explain she is only available part time (which is the truth) and hope it escalates to people that can change things.